# How to pass the Dynamic value for the same request in jmeter?

Tags: regex, jmeter, correlation, beanshell, blazemeter

In Jmeter, I have a scenario, that i need to fetch the job_id from the GET Request . so solution is using REGEX for fetching and using it for next requests. But for same GET request which is dynamic value change, How i need to generate the job_id for the same Request Url/Parameters.

#### GetRequest:

[image: GetRequest]

#### Parameter Value

[image: Parameter Value]

Answer (score 0):

I assume that JobID is auto incremental. Like 119750, 119751, and so on.

If so, then you can use "Counter" Config elements as shown in below image and Pass "${Count}" as value of JobID.

[Counter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XX2tf.png)